# Vue Router interfering with $nextTick (particles.js)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vue-router, particles.js

This is my first post. My issue is the following, I have a `vuejs` app that uses `vue-router` and one of the components in the vue uses `particle.js`. I was successfully able to integrate `particle.js` into my component using `$nextTick`, however when I added nested routes to the parent component of this said component, `particles.js` stopped working with no error. The main app is layered as follows:

**App.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <nav-bar />
    <Title />
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>
```

**Particle.js** is running in the 'title' component.

**which is as follows:**

```
<template>
  <div id="particles-js"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Title",

  mounted() {
    require("particles.js");
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.initParticlesJS();
    });
  },

  methods: {
    initParticlesJS() {
      /* eslint-disable */
      particlesJS("particles-js", {
        particles: {
          number: {
            value: 8,
            density: {
              enable: true,
              value_area: 800
            }
          },
          color: {
            value: "#2d3bff"
          },
          shape: {
            type: "circle",
            stroke: {
              width: 0,
              color: "#2d3bff"
            },
            polygon: {
              nb_sides: 5
            },
            image: {
              src: "img/github.svg",
              width: 100,
              height: 100
            }
          },
          opacity: {
            value: 0.5,
            random: false,
            anim: {
              enable: false,
              speed: 1,
              opacity_min: 0.1,
              sync: false
            }
          },
          size: {
            value: 10,
            random: true,
            anim: {
              enable: false,
              speed: 80,
              size_min: 0.1,
              sync: false
            }
          },
          line_linked: {
            enable: true,
            distance: 300,
            color: "#2d3bff",
            opacity: 0.8,
            width: 2
          },
          move: {
            enable: true,
            speed: 12,
            direction: "none",
            random: false,
            straight: false,
            out_mode: "out",
            bounce: false,
            attract: {
              enable: false,
              rotateX: 600,
              rotateY: 1200
            }
          }
        },
        interactivity: {
          detect_on: "canvas",
          events: {
            onhover: {
              enable: false,
              mode: "repulse"
            },
            onclick: {
              enable: true,
              mode: "push"
            },
            resize: true
          },
          modes: {
            grab: {
              distance: 800,
              line_linked: {
                opacity: 1
              }
            },
            bubble: {
              distance: 800,
              size: 80,
              duration: 2,
              opacity: 0.8,
              speed: 3
            },
            repulse: {
              distance: 400,
              duration: 0.4
            },
            push: {
              particles_nb: 4
            },
            remove: {
              particles_nb: 2
            }
          }
        },
        retina_detect: true
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
#particles-js {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

I think this might be an issue with the DOM or with the way components are rendered using nested routing because when I remove the  from the main component the particles work fine and when I add it again it doesn't seem to be running. But I'm afraid that it's a little out of my depth for something that was supposed to be a simple project.

**Update:**
I still don't know how to diagnose this. However, I tried using different routes and when I go into a route that doesn't exist, for example: `localhost:8080/#/route_that_doesnt_exist` the particles will show up, meaning that it only doesn't work when the page is rendering one of the nested routes. I hope this helps.

Comment: What do your component imports looks like? Is it really `<Title />` or `<title />`

Comment: it really is `<Title />` ! But what is strange is that the title still gets displayed when `<router-view>` gets added, simply the animation is not launching, which is what makes me think that it is in the `$nextTick` function